# Excel - lines running through spreadsheet

Tags: excel

Excel running on a MacBook Pro.

I have one spreadsheet which is displaying three diagonal lines from approximately A11 to L65 - L72. I have never created these lines and although when I scroll below row 72 and return to the top of the sheet they are removed from the display they then reappear.  They are causing me problems as I cannot print the spreadsheet either to printer or PDF without them appearing.
[Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gezpa.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It could be the relationships between cells. Please check [Display the relationships between formulas and cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507)